# How to use AdminLTE's Pace Page with Rails Turbo Links?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, progress-bar, turbolinks, adminlte

I'm using [AdminLTE](https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index.html) for my [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) app and I'd like to implement the [Pace Page](https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/pages/examples/pace.html) feature with **Turbo Links**.

How to do it?

Using the gem [nprogress-rails](https://github.com/caarlos0/nprogress-rails), I'm able to add similar loading screen. But I suppose using AdminLTE's built-in Pace Page feature would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

add the following into application.js:

```
$(document).on('page:fetch',   function() { NProgress.start(); });
$(document).on('page:change',  function() { NProgress.done(); });
$(document).on('page:restore', function() { NProgress.remove(); });
```

Comment: It's does not work yet. Thanks, it's a good step for me, I'd update as soon I get it working with these JS.